# Library error in Python (Pyaudio) for Mac

Tags: python, shared-libraries, pyaudio

import pyaudio._portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002):
symbol not found in flat namespace '_PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap'

I am not getting how to solve this problem so that i can input my voice in the code.
I have to solve and perform operations using pyaudio